# Jekyll install on Windows error?

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems, installation, jekyll

I'm not very knowledgeable with Ruby, but I want to try [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/). I'm using Windoows 7 64-bit and I have Ruby 2.0.0p451 installed and I installed the related development kit. When I enter `ruby dk.rb install`, I get the following messages:

```
[INFO] Skipping existing gem override for 'C:/Ruby200-x64'
[WARN] Skipping existing DevKit helper library for 'C:/Ruby200-x64'
```

and then when I try to install Jekyll with `gem install Jekyll`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Error installing jekyll:
ERROR: Failed to build the gem native extension.
```

If you need more from the message I got I can provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on the [rubyinstaller troubleshooting page](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Troubleshooting) on GitHub (go figure)
The command `REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor"` output an `AutoRun` message, which was the culprit. After deleting it with `REG DELETE "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor"` `AutoRun` I was able to install Jekyll. Finally!